# Trying to install libsndfile on Ubuntu 16

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, libsndfile

I've tried running

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile
> E: Unable to locate package libsndfile
```

So then I try

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1
```

It installs, but where, how?

```
find /usr/ -name libsndfile*
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
```

At the end of the day my goal is to get the lib to work for ruby, with either:

```
gem install sndfile
gem install ruby-audio
```

When I try installing ruby-audio, I get:

```
extconf.rb:21:in `<main>':   Can't find libsndfile (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) (RuntimeError)
```

So for some reason the library doesn't install properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you want to compile something against a library you'll need not only the library itself, which is usually one or more `.so` type files, but the header files that describe how the library works. These are often omitted unless you install the `-dev` version of the package:

```
apt-get install libsndfile-dev
```

This should give the Ruby `extconf.rb` enough information to compile and link against that library.